# Calculating Triplet-Triplet Spin-Orbit Coupling

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

According to the Q-Chem manual [1], the singlet-triplet spin-orbit couplings between a singlet excited state $I$ and a triplet excited state state $J$ is:
$$\langle\Phi_\text{singlet}^I|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^J\rangle = \sqrt{\sum_{m_s=0,\pm1}|\langle\Phi_\text{singlet}^I|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^{J,m_s}\rangle|^2}~.$$

The further elaborate on the triplet-triplet spin-orbit coupling to be:
$$\langle\Phi_\text{triplet}^I|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^J\rangle = \sqrt{\sum_{m_s=0,\pm1}|\langle\Phi_\text{triplet}^{I,m_s}|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^{J,m_s}\rangle|^2}~.$$

But shouldn't the latter actually be a double sum like:
$$\langle\Phi_\text{triplet}^I|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^J\rangle = \sqrt{\sum_{m_{s,i}=0,\pm1}\sum_{m_{s,j}=0,\pm1}|\langle\Phi_\text{triplet}^{I,m_{s,i}}|\hat{\mathrm H}_{SO}|\Phi_\text{triplet}^{J,m_{s,j}}\rangle|^2}~?$$

As of [porphyrin](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/30424/porphyrin)'s [comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/90004/calculating-triplet-triplet-spin-orbit-coupling#comment164504_90004), I'd like to add, why I think so.

The triplet-triplet SOC matrix looks like the following:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline m_{s,i}\text{\\} m_{s,j} & 0 & -1 & 1 \\\hline
  0 & 0 & a & a \\
  -1 & a & b & 0\\
  1 & a & 0 & b\\
  \hline
\end{array}

If the rules from the "single sum" would apply, only $b$ would count into the sum and $a$ would be neglected, because the summation only accounts for the diagonal elements.

---

[1] http://www.q-chem.com/qchem-website/manual/qchem50_manual/sect-tddft.html

Comment: I would agree if the total from all $m$ is needed then this would seem logical.